# Removing field highlight in Oracle Forms data block

Tags: oracle10g, oracleforms

In Oracle Forms 10g, when you programmatically navigate to a field in a data block using the GO_BLOCK or GO_ITEM built-in functions, and set the field to a certain value (in our case, the wildcard '%'), Forms will automatically highlight the value in the field.  Then when the user begins typing in that field, whatever value was there will be wiped out because it was highlighted.

Is there any way to navigate to a field, assign a value to the field, and set the cursor before the first character without highlighting the text in the field?

Answer (score 1):

For the item you are navigating to have you tried setting the value of "Keep Cursor Position" (shown in the screen shot below) to Yes?

[image]

Comment: I tried that but found I also had to set the Multi-Line property to Yes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found that setting the data item to Multi-line and setting the Keep Position property to Yes caused the form to set the cursor before the first character without highlighting the text in the field.  This is the desired performance.